# Authenticate with Azure using service principle in Pulumi

Tags: azure, pulumi

I have a Pulumi - program which works fine on my Dev-Machine. Configuarion is stored in Azure, also the Resources created are being stored in Azure.

To run this I set the following environment variables:

```
SET ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=<id>
```

Locally I login to Azure using `az login` which then asks me for my credentials. After that I can use `pulumi up` to update changes in Azure. This all works without any issues.

Now I want to achieve the same thing in Azure Devops using a release-pipeline. I use the "Azure CLI"- Task with correctly configured ARM-Connection. The task contains `pulumi up -s develop --yes` (where "develop" is my pulumi-stack)

I can see in the logs that the Azure-login works as expected, but pulumi throws the following error:
error:

> Error building AzureRM Client: Authenticating using the Azure CLI is only supported as a User (not a Service Principal). To authenticate to Azure using a Service Principal, you can use the separate 'Authenticate using a Service Principal' auth method  - instructions for which can be found here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret

While the error is quite clear and even contains a url to a solution to solve this: This does not really help me because I do not use terraform directly but pulumi instead.

TL;DR: How do I confgure pulumi cli to use a service principal authentication with Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options to configure Pulumi to authenticate with a Service Principal:

1. Set the environment variables `ARM_CLIENT_ID`, `ARM_CLIENT_SECRET`, `ARM_TENANT_ID`, and `ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID`, or
2. Set them using configuration

   ```
   pulumi config set azure:clientId <clientID>
   pulumi config set azure:clientSecret <clientSecret> --secret
   pulumi config set azure:tenantId <tenantID>
   pulumi config set azure:subscriptionId <subscriptionId>
   ```

Reference: [Service Principal Authentication](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/cloud-providers/azure/setup/#service-principal-authentication)

Comment: #1 works for me but #2 gives me the following:
error: building auth config: obtain subscription() from Azure CLI: Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: Error waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1

Comment: This sounds like a broken token file of the Azure CLI... Try `az login` again?

Comment: I am trying to do this with a SP in my CI... I will ask another question on SO.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do the same but from within the code instead of doing this from outside the app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are usign [azure-native](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/installation-configuration/#configuration-options) package instead of `azure` try `azure-native`. I.e.

```
pulumi config set azure-native:clientId <clientID>
pulumi config set azure-native:clientSecret <clientSecret> --secret
pulumi config set azure-native:tenantId <tenantID>
pulumi config set azure-native:subscriptionId <subscriptionId>
```